# ¿Como intercalar 2 colores en filas del DataGridView DevExpress? En C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, datagrid

Utilizé el evento RowStyle con el siguiente código:

```
private void dgvPersonalizadoInterior_RowStyle(object sender, RowStyleEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dgvPersonalizadoInterior.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    if ((i % 2) == 0)
                        e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    else
                        e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Estuve buscando información sobre el tema, pero no encontré nada.

Tienen alguna idea?

Comment: Nahuel, bienvenido!, para formular preguntas y recibir respuestas que te puedan ayudar, deberias profundizar mas en tu problema. Agregar tu codigo actual , algunas evidencias, que has intentado y ha fallado y el resultado esperado.

Comment: pasa por el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee el artículo [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si no entendí mal, lo que buscas es una fila de un color y la siguiente de otro, así por todo el listado que tienes en el grid.

Si es correcto lo que entendí, lo puedes hacer mediante el diseñador.

Prueba lo siguiente:

1.- Run Designer del **GridControl** 
2.- Seleccionas el **GridView** 
3.- Busca la Propiedad **Appearance** 
4.- Dentro de Appearance existe **EvenRow** y **OddRow** con propiedades específicas para dar estilo a dichas filas.

Ya es cuestión de que asignes el estilo que más estés buscando.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por la información.

Aunque para poder visualizar los colores intercalados en la grilla hay que activar
esto:

```
GridView1.OptionsView.EnableAppearanceEvenRow = true;
GridView1.OptionsView.EnableAppearanceOddRow = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la propiedad **HtmlDataCellPrepared** 
Por ejemplo yo tengo dos columnas que comparo y modifico el color de los que tengan cantidades diferentes.

```
    settings.HtmlDataCellPrepared = (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.DataColumn.FieldName == "decProdsPedidos" || e.DataColumn.FieldName == "decProdsSurtidos")
                {
                    decimal decProdsPedidos = Convert.ToDecimal(e.GetValue("decProdsPedidos"));
                    decimal decProdsSurtidos = Convert.ToDecimal(e.GetValue("decProdsSurtidos"));
                    if (decProdsPedidos != decProdsSurtidos)
                    {
                        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.GreenYellow;
                        e.Cell.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }       
            };
```